# Jenkins - How can I change the plugin directory?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, volume

Cheers everyone,

I am in a Kubernetes environment and Jenkins plugins are installed at image build time via means of Jenkins CLI.

This causes the Image to have all plugins I require in the JENKINS_HOME inside the image.

When running the image however we mount a single volume to the location of JENKINS_HOME as to persist all files in that location.

This obviously overlays the files of the image with the files on the volume. Classic problem.

Now: In "pure" Docker I was able to simply "re-mount" the plugin folder's location again (I won't go into detail to keep this a little shorter) to "pull it back up to the surface". Thus resulting in all files from the volume BUT the plugins folder from the image.

This functionality does not seem to work in Kubernetes anymore.

Thus I would like to change the directory in which Jenkins stores its plugins (when I install them during build time) so they won't be in JENKINS_HOME anymore and thus won't be "over-mounted" by the volume at runtime.

I am having a hard time finding a config value for the plugin directory. Is there one?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: Cheers! We're on 1.21 with AWS EKS, deployed via Terraform.